# D3.js and Ionic 2: Elements not in DOM on second page view

Tags: d3.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created a simple Ionic app for testing the integration of d3.js. It can be found here:
https://github.com/wberger/ionic2-d3js-test

I did the integration as follows:

1. Create an app with side navigation and a single page (`home.html`)
2. Add `home.html` to the menu.
3. Load d3.js in index.html:
   `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`
4. Add `<div id="chart"></div>` to `home.html`
5. Create the chart in `ngAfterViewInit()` in `home.ts`

The `home` template is defined as follows ([source](https://github.com/wberger/ionic2-d3js-test/blob/master/app/pages/home/home.html)):

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  The world is your oyster.
  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will be your guide.
  </p>
  <div id="chart"></div>
  <p>After</p>
</ion-content>
```

The chart creation is implemented as follows ([source](https://github.com/wberger/ionic2-d3js-test/blob/master/app/pages/home/home.ts)):

```js
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createChart();
  }

  createChart() {
    var chart = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .append("g");

    var rows = [
      {x: 1, y: 1},
      {x: 2, y: 2},
      {x: 3, y: 3},
    ];

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([0, 100])
            .domain([1, 3]);
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([100, 0])
            .domain([1, 3]);

    chart.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(rows)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("cx", (row) => { return xScale(row.x) })
      .attr("cy", (row) => { return yScale(row.y) })
      .attr("r", 3.5);
  }
```

When starting the app, the chart is displayed as intended. But when (re-)opening the page from the side menu, the chart is not there. When inspecting the TS/DOM in Google Chrome, I can observe the following behaviour when re-opening:

- `ngAfterViewInit()` gets called and in turn calls 'createChart()'
- The previously created SVG elements are still there
- A second SVG element is created and filled by `createChart()`

After `ngAfterViewInit()` the created SVG is gone. It seems that the DOM is replaced with the empty (or a cached??) template.

So my questions are:

- What goes wrong here? What should I know?
- How can I fix that?

Comment: Hello thewulf, did you had a chance to solve this issue and make d3js work within Ionic 2? Thank you for your feedback! Antoine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by building the chart as a component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-chart',
  inputs: ['options', 'data'],
  template: ``
})
export class MyChart implements OnChanges {

  el: any;
  options: MyChartOptions;
  data: MyChartData;

  chart: any;
  arcMap: any;

  /**
   * Initializes the component with the root element.
   */
  constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  /**
   * Handler for binding changes.
   * @param changes The changed bound values.
   */
  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.options) {
      this.updateWithOptions(this.options);
    }

    if (changes.data) {
      this.updateWithData(this.data);
    }
  }

  // handlers, drawing etc. ...
}
```

It can then be integrated as follows:

```
<my-chart [data]="chartData" [options]="chartOptions"></my-chart>
```

Don't forget to register the component in `app.module.ts`, e.g.:

```
import { MyChart } from '../components/charts/my-chart';

// ...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
    MyChart
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [MyApp],
  entryComponents: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    // ...
  ]
})
```